# Can an app read information from the lock screen?

Tags: android, notifications

I should start by saying that I'm not (yet) an Android developer. I've got a very specific, personal task that I'd like to achieve. If what I want to do is possible then it will be worth me learning enough to make it work. If it's impossible then I'll stick to what I already know!

I have type 1 diabetes and use a medical app which displays my blood glucose level on an Android phone's lock screen. There's a screenshot below. I'd like to be able to capture the information (particularly the number in the red box) and use it in other ways.

I've tested another app that reads Android notifications, but it only seems to have access to the popup messages that appear from an app. It doesn't see the persistent notifications on the lock screen.

So... is it possible for an app to read those lock screen notifications?

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image: notification on Android lockscreen]

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is possible with `NotificationListener`:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html#NotificationListener

The flags FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT or FLAG_NO_CLEAR will let you know if a certain notification is persistent.

Here is a sample project that I found useful demonstrating `NotificationListener`. In the `NotificationListenerExampleService.java`, you can simply change the `onNotificationPosted` method to find out if a notification is persistent:

```
@Override
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
    if (sbn.getPackageName().equals("package name of your desired app")) {
        if (!sbn.isClearable()) {
            Notification notif = sbn.getNotification();
            // get your desired data in the notif object
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can see the package name of an app by just simply going into its Google Play store page, and in the url you will find something like this:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=chat.rocket.ne2.reactnative&hl=en_CA
```

where the id field (**chat.rocket.ne2.reactnative**) is the package name.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll try that and will report back...